# Windows 10 Desktop Apps?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-preview

I recently moved from Win7 to Win10 (totally skipped 8 and 8.1).

I've got my desktop setup pretty nicely, but there is 1 thing that I am missing badly. Desktop Apps/Gadgets.

Windows came with Gadgets in Windows Vista, and I kept using them (mainly my own made ones) on Windows 7. Now I heard there is a hack of some kind, that will bring the Vista gadgets back, but I was really hoping that there would be some kind of Windows Apps that can live on your desktop (like what Mac offers)

**So my question is: is it possible to make apps for Windows 10 that actively live on the desktop?** Kind of like the Live Tiles in the Start Menu.

Comment: Gadgets are no longer supported.  They were removed from Vista due to security concerns.  They do not exist in Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 nor do they exist in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about Live Tiles on the Desktop but you could try this

> http://winaero.com/blog/desktop-gadgets-and-sidebar-for-windows-10/

In case the link becomes dead here are the instructions below (picked up from that page)

Get the installer from the following page: [Download the Sidebar](http://gadgetsrevived.com/download-sidebar/)
Follow the setup wizard, it will take you through a few simple steps.
Close the setup wizard, and right click the desktop. The Gadgets item will be there.

Do note that your gadgets might appear a little weird because of changes to Aero in Windows 10.

Comment: Edited the answer @Ramhound